# Call a nested Rails route from Ember App

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rails-api

How to call a nested Rails route from Ember app if I don't need nested templates ?
I have the following routes in Rails router:

```
# routes.rb
resources :shops do
  resources :shop_languages
end
```

So to get a list of shop languages the `shops/:shop_id/shop_languages` should be hit.

Here is ShopsLanguagesController:

```
# controllers/shop_languages_controller.rb
class ShopLanguagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_shop

  def index
    json_response @shop.shop_languages, :ok, include: 'language'
  end

  private

    def find_shop
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
    end
end
```

In Ember app I have the routes defined as follows:

```
# router.js
Router.map(function() {
...
  this.route('languages', { path: '/shops/:shop_id/shop_languages'});
});
```

In Ember `application.hbs` template the languages link is defined as follows

```
# application.hbs
{{#link-to 'languages' currentUser.user.shop.id class="nav-link"}}
..
{{/link-to}}
```

In Ember `languages.js` route handler, I'm trying to load shop languages:

```
# routes/languages.js
model(params) {
  return this.store.query('shop-language', { shop_id: params.shop_id })
}
```

Ember hits `/shop-languages` end-point instead of the nested one `shops/:shop_id/shop_languages`.

Of course, I've defined the corresponding models on Ember side:

```
# models/shop-language.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  shop: DS.belongsTo('shop'),
  language: DS.belongsTo('language'),
  modified_by:  DS.attr('string')
});
```

What is wrong with that and how to get it work? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The short answer; requests made to the server do not match your route structure, but are based on your model and the adapter you're using e.g. REST vs JSON API based on that the URL called at your server may differ.

So to get your `/shop/:id/` added as a prefix for your `shop-language` query you'll have to override the default behavior of your adapter.

To get started generate an adapter for your model
`ember g adapter shop-language`

In your new adapter you'll probably have to override 2 functions

1) `query` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/adapters/rest.js#L549)

2) `urlForQuery` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L188)

Also look at `buildURL` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L55) which handles all different scenarios.

In 1) you probably want to remove the `shop_id` from the query params so you don't end up with an URL like `/shops/1/shop-languages?shop_id=1`

In 2) you'll have to add `/shops/1` to your URL based on the passed query params

Comment: I'm using `JSONAPIAdapter`(defined in `adapters/application.js` where there is nothing special but `authorizer` and `host` values defined. Sounds a little bit weird and too complicated for the moment. Thank you for your response. I'll search for more example and details to be able to implement it.

Comment: by convention dynamic segments should use underscore
`this.route('languages', { path: 'shops/:shop_id/languages'});`
So you'd call
`return this.store.query('shop-language', { shop_id: params.shop_id });`
This should already fix your duplication on the Rails side

Comment: nope, I get `Error while processing route: languages Ember Data Request GET /shops/undefined/languages returned a 404`. I modified as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dguettler here is a solution I came to to get it work.

**On Ember side**

Declare the languages route as follows:

```
#router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('languages', { path: 'shops/:shopId/languages'});
  ..
});
```

Modify/create `languages.js` route handler as follows:

```
#routes/languages.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('shop-language', { shopId: params.shopId});
  }
});
```

Create/modify `shop-language.js` adapter as follows:

```
#adapters/shop-language.js

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  urlForQuery (query) {
    return this._buildShopUrl(query.shop_id)
  },

urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot) {
  return this._buildShopUrl(snapshot.belongsTo('shop').id);
},

urlForDeleteRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
  return this._buildShopUrl(snapshot.id, id);
},

_buildShopUrl(shop_id, id) {
  if (id) {
    return `shops/${shop_id}/languages/${id}`;
  }
  return `shops/${shop_id}/languages`;
 }
});
```

Add a link to load shop languages to your template:

```
#templates/application.hbs

...
{{#link-to 'languages' currentUser.user.shop.id class="nav-link"}}
...
{{/link-to}}
```

Display shop languages in `languages.hbs` template:

```
#templates/languages.hbs

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  {{#each model as |lang|}}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{lang.tag}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**On Rails API side**

Declare a shop_languages resource as nested route:

```
#routes.rb
...
resources :shops do
  resources :shop_languages, path: '/languages'
end
```

Load shop languages in `ShopLanguagesController`:

```
#controllers/shop_languages_controller.rb

class ShopLanguagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_shop

  def index
    json_response @shop.languages, :ok
  end

  private

  def find_shop
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  end
end
```

I'll have one thing to do - remove `?shopId=613` from the URL and fix the params hash that contains a kind of double values:

```
Started GET "/shops/613/languages?shopId=613" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-23 10:05:53 +0100
Processing by ShopLanguagesController#index as JSONAPI
  Parameters: {"shopId"=>"613", "shop_id"=>"613"}
```